# Symfony 2 - How to keep in sync the models between two symfony application

Tags: php, git, symfony

I need to keep in **sync** the same **models** between **two symfony2 applications** located in two different server.

**I think to use Git** for this work with something like "*repository inside a repository*".
This is a viable method?

Anyone has already done something of similar?

Answer (score 4):

Put the models in an extra bundle and git repository. Then refer to it via composer and it will be installed in de vendor dir of the two projects. After that you need only to edit the extra bundle.

http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package